# Promise.all not waiting for Promise to resolve

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, frontend, es6-promise

when I make a request to the server, the data gets returned as a promise (as expected) which contains the correct data, but for some reason, the program does not execute properly.

Also, this program worked prior to me uploading it on Zeit.

Fetch Request:

1) I'm aware I don't need 'content-type': 'application/json'. Removing it does not effect the program.

2) This is a GET request and the endpoint works fine. Also, when I execute this same exact request in Postman, I get the correct result.

```
// CODE ABOVE DOES NOT MATTER
       .then( ([hours, employees, dayLabor]) => {
           // hours, employees, and dayLabor are empty lists for this exercise '[]'

            let business = fetch(`${config.URL}/${TokenService.getId()}`,
            {
                headers: {
                    'content-type': 'application/json',
                    'table':'business',
                    'Authorization':`bearer ${TokenService.getAuthToken()}`
                }
            })
            .then(data => {
              console.log('business: ',data, ' or ', data.json());
              if (!data.ok){
                  return data.json().then(e => Promise.reject(e));}

              return data.json();
            });


            return Promise.all([business, hours, employees, dayLabor]);
      })
      .then( ([business, hours, employees, dayLabor]) => {  
            // THIS is never executed?

            console.log('completed');            

            //fetch has been completed and the state has been updated so set "fetched" to true

            this.setState({business, hours, employees, 'dayLabor': dayLabor.length>0? this.sort(dayLabor):[], fetched: true});


      })
      .catch(error => {
            console.error({error});
      });
```

The output result (blotted out the url for privacy reasons):

```
business:  
Response {type: "cors", url: "https://xxxxxx.herokuapp.com/1", redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …}
type: "cors"
url: "https://xxxxxxxx.herokuapp.com/1"
redirected: false
status: 200
ok: true
statusText: "OK"
headers: Headers {}
body: (...)
bodyUsed: true
__proto__: Response
  or  
Promise {<pending>}
__proto__: Promise
[[PromiseStatus]]: "resolved"
[[PromiseValue]]: Array(1)
0: {id: 1, business_name: "Fake Company Inc"}
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
```

I want to access the object inside "[[PromiseValue]]". I'm confused as to why this isn't working, especially since it did work when I ran it locally? It seems like the issue lies with either the "business" variable or the "Promise.all" not waiting for the promise to resolve.

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated, I've searched constantly and can't find any sort of solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One particular problem is that you can only call `data.json()` once.  It reads the rest of the http response (the body) and then parses it).  Once it's read, it can't be read again.  So, when you do:

```
console.log(..., data.json())
```

You are instructing the response object to read the response body and return a promise that will tell you when it's done.  You then log that promise which is not yet fulfilled.  And, then you drop that promise on the floor and never do anything with it.

Then, later in your code, you do

```
return data.json();
```

But, there is no more response body, it's already been read.  You can't call this more than once.  So, this won't work.

So, the first thing to fix is to remove the `data.json()` from your `console.log()` and let just the

```
return data.json();
```

handle reading the body and parsing the response once.

So, change to this:

```
   // CODE ABOVE DOES NOT MATTER
   .then( ([hours, employees, dayLabor]) => {
       // hours, employees, and dayLabor are empty lists for this exercise '[]'

        let business = fetch(`${config.URL}/${TokenService.getId()}`,
        {
            headers: {
                'content-type': 'application/json',
                'table':'business',
                'Authorization':`bearer ${TokenService.getAuthToken()}`
            }
        }).then(data => {
          console.log('business: ', data);
          if (!data.ok){
              return data.json().then(e => Promise.reject(e));}

          return data.json();
        });


        return Promise.all([business, hours, employees, dayLabor]);
  }).then( ([business, hours, employees, dayLabor]) => {  
        // THIS is never executed?

        console.log('completed');            

        //fetch has been completed and the state has been updated so set "fetched" to true

        this.setState({business, hours, employees, 'dayLabor': dayLabor.length>0? this.sort(dayLabor):[], fetched: true});


  }).catch(error => {
        console.error({error});
  });
```

Comment: Wow! I ran into this same problem 2 weeks ago when working on the server side, can't believe I forgot about this (facepalm). I appreciate your answer man!! I wasted too much time on this lol

Comment: @ezg - It's subtle.  It would actually be nice if the `Response` object threw a very specific exception if you tried to call `.json()` more than once.  That would save people lots of time.  I looked at your code 5 times and had several other theories before I realized this actual problem.  It is subtle.  Anyway, glad to help.